# Application requires Microsoft.TeamFoundation. Controls Version 11.0.0.0. be installed in the Global Assembly Cache

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I've develop an application using Visual Studio 2012 and published it. When my client tries to install it, it says it cannot install as the application requires the assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation. Controls Version 11.0.0.0. be installed in the Global Assembly Cache. I realise I need to add a dependency when installing, but which one?

Comment: Hmm, a dependency to TeamFoundation?
What kind of application do you develop? TeamFoundation is not a everyday assembly.
YOu can add dependencies in the "publish" section of Clickonce

Comment: I have no idea why it needs this, I'm not using TeamFoundation in any way...

Comment: Do you happen to know which dependency I need to add for TeamFoundation?

Comment: Thats totally weird, when you are ot using TEamFoundation. As a suggestion: Make a new project and add all code from the old project.Most ClickOnce Problems can be "solved" that way...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll
```

in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5